# Potential difference in a capacitor

Tags: voltage, transistors, capacitor, charge

As I simulated the circuit below, it shows that the potential difference across Cx is the amount of potential being stored on C3 and C4 during charging phase. How do we get the potential difference of a capacitor? And how did this happen? What theory is behind this operation?

[image: circuit simulated]

Comment: Can you ask the question differently? The voltage over Cx is the voltage of C4 minus the voltage of C3. That's just how the circuit is laid out. Surely you're asking about something else...

Comment: @djambalong: Can you give more infors on the circuits, or where the diagram comes from? What's the initial state of the circuit?