# Determining the voltage and charges across each capacitor

Tags: voltage, capacitor, charge, charge-pump

Since someone edited my question and asked me to post a new question instead with the edits I did, so here is the new schematic for this question:

Can someone help me find the voltage and charge across each of the capacitors? This is not just a simple/ parallel circuit so I am having a problem in formulating the right equation on how to find the voltage and charge across each capacitor.This is actually one branch of a charge pump wherein capacitors pump charges to the load capacitor, CL. I also want to know how charge transfer occurs between capacitors.
[image]

Below is the original circuit:
[image]

Comment: Please label all the nodes in your schematic so we can discuss them and you will know what we are talking about.

Comment: Hint: The node connecting R2, C2, and Cx has no dc path to ground, so there is no unique solution to your problem. (You see why it would have been easier if you would have labeled that node "node 2" or something?)

Comment: Finally, have you tried entering the circuit into a SPICE-like simulator? What result did you get? What about the result don't you understand?

Comment: Charge-pump? Then it should have some switches in the circuit? Right?

Comment: the switches has some resistance, thus, the resistors there are where the switches located @diverger. And at that moment the two are closed.

Comment: @ThePhoton I've made the corrections already. What do you mean by "no unique solution"? I've already simulated it in SYNOPSYS but what I need is how did I get those values by mathematical equation or doing some pen and paper analysis.

Comment: I mean the voltage at node b could be anything.

Comment: @ThePhoton I've tried simulating it by varying the capacitance of Cx and this is what I've observed: (Cx=C1=C2; Vout=1.33xVd and Cx=1/2 C1=1/2 C2; Vout=1.5xVd), my problem is how can I put this relationship into equation?

Comment: Is Vd meant to be an ac source? You need to add that information to the question if it is.

Comment: Also, if you want to talk about "Vout" you need to say what node it is measured at.

Comment: Btw, shouldn't a straightforward application of Thevenin theorem (in s domain) help ?

Comment: It's a DC source @ThePhoton. Is my equivalent circuit correct based on the original circuit I've posted? Is it right that I've connected C2 directly to the Vd source just like what I did?

Comment: Oh, the original one is more clear, i think i should do some editing to my answer.

Comment: Please @diverger, since I've checked your solution and input values to the capacitors and Vd, there's a mismatch on the values I got from the simulation.

Comment: R1, and R2 are switches, right? Can they be closed at the same time?

Comment: @diverger this is the cmos equivalent of the charge pump http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/129226/potential-difference-in-a-capacitor , the circuit above only represents one branch of the circuit where the PMOS are 'ON' that acts as switch that is 'CLOSED'. Since the operation on the other branch is just the same.

Answer (score 2):

Considering the top circuit :

Applying KCL at the nodes :

A : (Vd - Va) / R1 = ( Va / sC1) + ( (Va - Vb) / sCx)

B : ( (Va - Vb) / sCx ) + ( (Vd - Vb) / sC2) = ( Vb - VL) / R2

L : ( (Vb - VL) / R2 ) = VL / sCL

3 equations for 3 unknowns.

( Don't forget to put Laplace transform of input ie of Vd).

(Did I miss something ?)

Comment: I've tried this solution which is very lengthy but at the end evaluating s to infinity for steady state I got an answer of zero. So, might as well try another solution.

Comment: I've reviewed it together with my instructor and we seemed to find no error in the process of solving it (evaluating algebra, nodal analysis, etc). Somebody told me to try the charge transfer but I had a problem analyzing it.

Comment: @djambalong . Yes the solution will be lengthy cuz you asked for voltage across all capacitors. And btw, why take limit s-> infinity ? For steady state, you use final value theorem for laplace transform acc to which you take lim s->0 ( s*F(s) ).

Comment: @djambalong . Also, if you evaluate s to infinity, you will get initial values, as per initial value theorem. And since you are getting zero, this suggests that indeed my solution should be correct, since all voltages are zero initially.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the botton circuit, it can be calculated as folows. As you know Kirchoff applies in each node all the time. Instead of writing Kirchoff using currents, we do it using charge (current integral over time):

a) $$Q_{R1}=Q_{C1}+Q_{Cx}$$

b) $$Q_{Cx}=Q_{C2}+Q_{CL}$$

The total charge in each capacitor, at the end, is its initial charge plus the charge that has circulated afterwards, i.e. QC1total=QC1initial + QC1 (in previous equation).

Therefore the initial charges (before current starts to flow) must be known to solve the problem. We will assume the initial charge of all capacitors is 0, and therefore QC1total=0+QC1=QC1, QC2total=QC2, etc.

Using second law of Kirchoff we can now write the final voltages, knowing that final currents will be 0, and therefore there is no voltage drop in resistors.

I) $$-Vd+V1=0  \rightarrow -Vd+\frac {Q_{C1}} {C1}=0$$

II) $$-V1+Vx+V2+Vd=0 \rightarrow \frac{-Q_{C1}} {C1}+\frac {Q_{Cx}} {Cx}+\frac {Q_{C2}} {C2}+Vd=0$$

III) $$-Vd-V2+Vout=0 \rightarrow -Vd-\frac {Q_{C2}} {C2}+\frac {Q_{CL}} {CL}=0$$

With those 3 equations plus the equation in b) you get 4 equations with 4 unknowns.

The equation in b) is saying in fact that \$\Delta Q_{Cx}=\Delta Q_{C2}+\Delta Q_{CL}\$, i.e. $$Q_{Cx}-Q_{C2}-Q_{CL}=Q_{previousCx}-Q_{previousC2}-Q_{previousCL}$$

Taking equation II, III and the last one, you can write in matrix form
$$ \left( \begin{array}{c} 0 \\ Vd\\ Q_{previousCx}-Q_{previousC2}-Q_{previousCL} \end{array} \right)  =  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\frac 1 {Cx} & \frac 1 {C2} & 0 \\
0 & -\frac 1 {C2} & \frac 1 {CL} \\
1 & -1 & -1 \end{array} \right) \cdot \left( \begin{array}{c} Qx \\ Q2\\ QL \end{array} \right)$$

This can be solved by inverting the matrix and multiplying by the vector in the left where You must use the previous values of capacitor's charge (at the beginning they will be 0).

After doing this, you should get the equations for the other value of CLK. You will see that the matrix doesn't change, only the vector changes (Vd swaps position with 0) and you will use as Qprevious the charges obtained in the previous step. After multiplying you will get the new values of Q and you can iterate again with other value of CLK.

You will see that the output voltage has a ripple (oscillates between 2 values). For your simulations choose a slow clock and you'll see that same ripple. If the clock is fast, the output voltage won't have ripple, but its final value will be the average between the 2 values obtained from equations.

Example using Vd=5V, C1=1uF, Cx=0.1 uF, C2=1uF, CL=1uF and a slow CLK of 10 Hz, here is the simulation:
[image: Simulation 10 Hz]

You can see it oscillates between 2.619 V and 238.1 mV.

We get those same results solving, in Matlab, the equations previously stated:
[image: Equations solved]

If you increase clock, the output voltage becomes smooth as you can see in this simulation (CLK changed to 100 kHz):
[image]

The final voltage is 1.43 V, which you can recognize as the average between 2.619 V and 238.1 mV.

Comment: thanks @Roger C. but why is it that the resistor isn't included in performing the KVL?

Comment: Because when the capacitors are charged the current I stops to flow, i.e. I=0 A. Therefore the voltage drop in the resistors V=I·R=0·R=0 V. Of course this is assuming that input voltage (CLK in your diagram) is steady enough time to allow the capacitors to be fully charged.

Comment: That means there is an initial charge across the capacitors?how could i get the initial charge @Roger C. ? I've tried solving it and I assume that the value in pF of capacitor Cx should affect the Vout based on my simulation results but when I subsituted values on it the output is still Vd in just one branch. Adding the two branches would result to twice Vd. But Cx should affect the Vout, like, when Cx=1/2 C1; Vout=1.5xVd.

Comment: @djambalong, I've updated the answer.

Comment: @djambalong, I followed this sign convention for voltages and charges in vertical components: + top and - bottom and for horizontal components + left and - right. Note: always considering the bottom circuit in your question.

Comment: You said @Roger C. that the resistors were not included in performing KVL since current stops to flow when capacitors are charged, that is at steady state. "After multiplying you will get the new values of Q and you can iterate again with other value of CLK" , based on that why do we have to iterate again with other clock values if it's already at its steady state? That means the capacitors are not yet fully charged and the equation lacks the elements resistors, R1 and R2. And how about the time constant RC?

Comment: @djambalong, we do have to iterate again when CLKs changes because the capacitors voltages are not in equilibrium any more (input voltages changed). Anyway, you can see that equations are fine because Matlab calculations from those equations match exactly with multisim simulations. Try to simulate the bottom circuit of this question and you'll see.

Comment: The equations find final voltage after each clock change assuming that the clock will keep its new state enough time to reach steady voltages. If clock is very fast for the time constants involved, the real waveform will converge to the average of the 2 values obtained from the equations as it is explained in my answer.

Comment: Hello @Roger C. on the next cycle this is what happens or the matrix http://imgur.com/zI4maq4 since based on the original circuit the cmos equivalent circuit here http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/129226/potential-difference-in-a-capacitor?noredirect=1#comment285422_129226 it has two branches so for the next cycle the capacitors C1 and C2 also changes nodes, C1 now is connected to node b and C2 to node a.

Comment: incase you're confused on what it looks like with two branches here http://imgur.com/w9ud7WM switches S1 and S2 close at the same time and S3 and S4 close on the next switching cycle.

Comment: @djambalong, I see. The two cycles are then quite different! You must find the matrix for each cycle and then iterate, just as I did for the circuit in this question. You can follow the same steps I followed here. You'll probably end up with 4x4 matrices because the charge on C1 must be taken into account at the next cycle. Try to solve and if it matches simulation results then you're done, otherwise post your solution attempt and we'll find out the problem!

Comment: hello @Roger C. I've tried it solving using this matrix form http://imgur.com/YpmEcw8 I bet I there's something wrong about it since I don't get the right answer, it doesn't coincide with my simulations.

Comment: What I did @Roger C. was add the voltage from the charges I got in the first cycle by the matrix above and the voltage from the charges I got in the matrix shown here for the next cycle http://imgur.com/YpmEcw8 . Is my process correct? And it seems to have discrepancy from the values I got in the simulation.